# Flattening aluminum sheets with a hot iron - what is happening?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I saw [this](https://www.instructables.com/Flatten-Soda-Cans/?amp_page=true) web page recently that gave advice for re- using aluminum cans by cutting off the top and bottom, cutting the can down the middle, and flattening the aluminum by laying it out under a hot iron for a few minutes. The iron was set to maximum heat (220C I believe). The video on the page showed this happening. (https://www.instructables.com/Flatten-Soda-Cans/?amp_page=true)

What is the mechanism by which this flattening is achieved? Was the aluminum heated to its glass transition temperature, then the pressure from the weight of the iron set it in a flat shape?
If a number of aluminum sheets were stacked on top of each other, could the action be repeated with the same heat and pressure?

Answer (score 2):

The Aluminium has been [annealed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annealing_(materials_science)) - its properties changed by heating and then cooling.

When deformed the microscopic grain structure of aluminum is altered during bending.  The more Aluminium is deformed the harder it is to to deform it further and this is called work-hardening.  Eventually the grain structure cannot experience any more stress and the aluminium can become permanently deformed or even crack and break.

If after bending the Aluminium is heat treated, annealed, as might be done with a very hot iron, the grain structure returns to its original configuration and the metal becomes easier to deform back to its original shape.

If one was to do this professionally the temperature, ideally between $300$ and $400\,^\circ\rm C$, and time of heating and cooling would be carefully controlled to achieve the best result to improve the ductility and increase the softness af the Aluminium.